# How to process late tuples from BaseWindowedBolt?

Tags: serialization, apache-storm

I am developing an Apache Storm (v2.5.0) topology that reads events from a spout (`BaseRichSpout`), counts the number of events in tumbling windows (`BaseWindowedBolt`), and prints the count (`BaseRichBolt`). The topology works fine, but there are some out-of-order events in my dataset. The `BaseWindowedBolt` provides `withLateTupleStream` method to route late events to a separate stream. However, when I try to process late events, I get a serialization exception:

```
`Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.storm.shade.com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.storm.shade.com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap.class);
Serialization trace:
defaultResources (org.apache.storm.task.WorkerTopologyContext)
context (org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:575) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:79) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:508) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:557) ~[kryo-4.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesSerializer.serializeInto(KryoValuesSerializer.java:38) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleSerializer.serialize(KryoTupleSerializer.java:40) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.WorkerState.checkSerialize(WorkerState.java:613) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.ExecutorTransfer.tryTransferLocal(ExecutorTransfer.java:101) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.ExecutorTransfer.tryTransfer(ExecutorTransfer.java:66) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.LocalExecutor$1.tryTransfer(LocalExecutor.java:36) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltOutputCollectorImpl.boltEmit(BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java:112) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltOutputCollectorImpl.emit(BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java:65) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:42) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.topology.WindowedBoltExecutor.execute(WindowedBoltExecutor.java:313) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.tupleActionFn(BoltExecutor.java:212) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.Executor.accept(Executor.java:294) ~[storm-client-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    ... 6 more`
```

I have defined my topology as below:

```
public class TestTopology {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TESTING_ALWAYS_TRY_SERIALIZE, true);
        config.registerSerialization(TupleImpl.class);
        config.registerSerialization(Fields.class);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        try (LocalCluster.LocalTopology topology = cluster.submitTopology("testTopology", config, getTopology().createTopology())) {
            Thread.sleep(50000);}
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
    static TopologyBuilder getTopology(){
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("eventSpout", new LateEventSpout());
        builder.setBolt("windowBolt", new WindowBolt().withTumblingWindow(BaseWindowedBolt.Duration.seconds(10)).
                        withTimestampField("time").
                        withLateTupleStream("lateEvents")).
                        shuffleGrouping("eventSpout");
        builder.setBolt("latePrintBolt", new LatePrintBolt()).
                        shuffleGrouping("windowBolt", "lateEvents");
        builder.setBolt("printBolt", new PrintBolt()).shuffleGrouping("windowBolt");
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Where `LateEventSpout` is

```
public class LateEventSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private List<Long> eventTimes;
    private int currentTime = 0;
    private int id = 1;
    public LateEventSpout () {
        eventTimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i<= 61; i++) {
            eventTimes.add(Instant.EPOCH.plusSeconds(i).toEpochMilli());
        } // [epoch+1, epoch+2, .., epoch+61]
    }
    @Override
    public void open(Map<String, Object> conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }
    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        int eventId = id++;
        Long eventTime = eventTimes.get(currentTime++);
        if (currentTime == eventTimes.size()){
            currentTime = 0;      // reset time to zero so we have OOO events
        }
        collector.emit(new Values(eventId, eventTime));
    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("id", "time"));
    }
}
```

And `WindowBolt` is:

```
public class WindowBolt extends BaseWindowedBolt {
    OutputCollector collector;
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map<String, Object> topoConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector){
        this.collector = collector;
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(TupleWindow inputWindow) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Tuple event : inputWindow.get()){
            sum++;
        }
        collector.emit(new Values(inputWindow.getStartTimestamp(), inputWindow.getEndTimestamp(), sum));
    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("start", "end", "sum"));
    }
}
```

And `PrintBolt` just prints the `windowBolt` output. (`LatePrintBolt` is similar)

```
public class PrintBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    @Override
    public void prepare(Map<String, Object> topoConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple input) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Start: %d, End: %d, Sum:%d", input.getLongByField("start"), input.getLongByField("end"), input.getIntegerByField("sum")));
    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    }
}
```

If I don't set the `LatePrintBolt` in `TopologyBuilder`, I get the correct results

```
Start: 0, End: 10000, Sum:10
Start: 10000, End: 20000, Sum:10
Start: 20000, End: 30000, Sum:10
Start: 30000, End: 40000, Sum:10
Start: 40000, End: 50000, Sum:10
Start: 50000, End: 60000, Sum:10
```

However, when I try to print lateEvents stream, I get the same output but on the first late event, I get the above-mentioned exception.

I have debugged the issue. When [WindowedBoltExecutor](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/18341682ce90976c173ecf9ac68582b1626bda8a/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/topology/WindowedBoltExecutor.java#L313) receives a late tuple, it emits the late tuple but [BoltOutputCollectorImpl](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/18341682ce90976c173ecf9ac68582b1626bda8a/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/executor/bolt/BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java#L110) rewraps it in a new Tuple. Now, this new tuple contains `WorkerTopologyContext` which is not serializable, hence, the error.

I would like to know how can I process the late tuples.